# The dotnet sonarscanner is running a node command for some reason and throwing "Failure during analysis, Node.js command to start eslint-bridge"

Tags: .net-core, sonarqube, sonarscanner

I'm getting a non fatal exception while running the dotnet sonarscanner utility to send data to our sonarqube instance.

During "dotnet sonarscanner end" command an exception is being thrown of "Failure during analysis, Node.js command to start eslint-bridge was: /usr/bin/node /builds/app-namespace/app-name/.sonarqube/out/.sonar/.sonartmp/eslint-bridge-bundle/node_modules/eslint-bridge/bin/server 44002
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to start server (10s timeout)"

Im currently running the command in an alpine docker container with
node : v10.14.2
dotnetcore: 2.2.3

The node and npm commands are available from the path and I have also specified the sonar.nodejs.executable in the sonarqube xml config.

Additionally what is the node package used for relating to a dotnet project?

The content is still being deployed to our sonarqube instance but I would like to understand the  cause of the exception.

Answer (score 0):

For C#/VB.NET code, the code analysis takes place in the build step because the SonarC#/VB.NET rules are written as Roslyn rules.

However, for most other languages analysed by SonarQube/Cloud, the analysis takes place in the scanner `end` step. The scanner downloads the language plugins from the SonarQube/Cloud server and calls each one to give it the chance to analyse any files it can handle.

The SonarJS plugin works with ESLint which uses NodeJS i.e. the node package is being used to analyse JavaScript files.